# Autocomplete response

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to 'popup' jquery autocomplete result under a textbox using the popover components of bootstrap.

I render results of the autocomplete query in an hidden div (#wrapper) and I want on render completion to set the content of my popover and show it.

For this I've overloaded the `_renderItem` function which append my results' divs inside the hidden container (#wrapper).

I thought the `response` function is called when _renderItem calls are done but I'm missing something as response function is never called.

Any solution?

Thanks!

```
$("#bookSearch")
             .autocomplete({
                 minLength: 0,
                 source: '/Autocomplete/Books',
                 focus: function (event, ui) {
                     $("#bookSearch").val(ui.item.label);
                     return false;
                 },
                 search: function(event, ui) {
                     $('#wrapper').empty();
                 },
                 response: function (event, ui) {
                    $('#bookSearch').popover('destroy');
                    $('#bookSearch').popover({
                            html: true,
                            placement: 'bottom',
                            content: $('#wrapper').html()
                    });
                    $('#bookSearch').popover('show');
                 }

             })
             .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                 $('<div class="media"></div>')                             
                                    .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                                    .append("<a class=\"pull-left\" href=\"#\"><img class=\"media-object\" src=\""
                                    + item.ImgUrl
                                    + "\"></a><div class=\"media-body\"><h6 class=\"media-heading\">"
                                    + item.Name
                                    + "</h6>"
                                    + item.Author + "</div>").appendTo('#wrapper');


             };
```

Comment: Is there a good reason you're using jquery UI's .autocomplete, when Bootstrap has its own .typeahead? http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead

Comment: `response` was added in 1.9. Are you using 1.9? Additionally, response is mostly used to manipulate the data before it's suggested (right *before* `_renderItem` if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: Ok first I was using jquery ui 1.8.20, and i think as stated by Judah that i can customize the bootstrap typehead to do what i want.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by adding to my css file a z-index style for the autocomplete.

```
.ui-autocomplete {
  z-index: 10000;
}
```

Remember to set a higher value for the `z-index` if it is necessary. Just for the record I have something like this in the HTML file

```
<div class="ui-widget">
   <label for="employee">Employee:</label>
   <input id="employee" type="text" name="employee" />
</div>
```